# Generate Row Number for every 3 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want generate number for every three rows

```
CREATE TABLE #test(period INT)

INSERT INTO #test
VALUES      (602),(603),(604),(605),(606),(607),(608),(609)
```

I know we can generate sequence using `row_number` window function or `while` loop or `cursor`

```
SELECT period,
       ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY period) - 1 ) / 3 + 1
FROM   #test
```

**Result;**

```
+--------+-----+
| period | seq |
+--------+-----+
|    602 |   1 |
|    603 |   1 |
|    604 |   1 |
|    605 |   2 |
|    606 |   2 |
|    607 |   2 |
|    608 |   3 |
|    609 |   3 |
+--------+-----+
```

Is there any other way to achieve this **mathematically**. There will not be any gaps between the periods

Comment: As far as I am concerned, there is no better way to do so. After all, this is what ROW_NUMBER has been designed for, no? Why do you want to use another approach?

Comment: Why would you want to use an other method if this is working fine? Is there a reason you want to do it more mathematically?

Comment: @Saypontigohe & @Tyron78 - Original requirement way more complex than this. I am using that sequence in `partition by` of another window function. Because of `Row_Number` query become very slow

Comment: is there a minimum period number in your dataset?

Comment: @scsimon - no it can start with any number.. But always number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mathematical or arithmetic approach could be to use the period numbers themselves:

```
-- table init here
DECLARE @MIN_PERIOD INT = (SELECT MIN(period) FROM #test)

SELECT period,
       (period - @MIN_PERIOD) / 3 + 1 AS seq
FROM   #test
```

This works as long as "there will not be any gaps between the periods" remains true.

If you need a `WHERE` clause on the main query, also apply it to the `SELECT MIN()` query. Will work as long as the `WHERE` does not cause period gaps.

Comment: Nice one... didn't figure this one out.

Comment: Great.. that was helpful

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to achieve this with the `NTILE()` function but I don't think that it is more efficient than `ROW_NUMBER()`, mainly because this method has to get the total count to determine the amount of groups.

**Create test environment:**

```
/*  -- SQL 2016
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test;
GO
*/

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #test

CREATE TABLE #test(period INT);
GO

INSERT INTO #test -- Make it bigger
VALUES      (602),(603),(604),(605),(606),(607),(608),(609);
GO 51
```

**ROW_NUMBER Method:**

```
SELECT /*ROW_NUM*/ period,
       ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY period) - 1 ) / 3 + 1
FROM   #test;
GO
```

[image: ROW_NUMBER]

IO and Time performances:
*Shortened for readability*

> (400 row(s) affected) Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads
>   0, physical reads 0
>   '#test_00000000000E'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 85
>   ms.

**NTILE Method**

```
DECLARE @ntile_var int;

SELECT @ntile_var = COUNT(*) FROM #test;

SELECT /*NTILE*/period
    , NTILE(@ntile_var / 3) OVER (ORDER BY period)
FROM #test
```

IO and Time performances:
*Shortened for readability*

> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   0 ms.
>
> Table
>   '#test__00000000000E'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> (400 row(s) affected) Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3, logical reads
>   811, physical reads 0
>    Table
>   '#test___00000000000E'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 93

[image: NTILE]

Both of these give the same results:

[image: Results_GroupsOf3]

But **there is a caveat!**
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175126.aspx#Anchor_3) put it sufficiently as (emphasis added)

> **If the number of rows in a partition is not divisible by
>   integer_expression, this will cause groups of two sizes that differ by
>   one member**. Larger groups come before smaller groups in the order
>   specified by the OVER clause. For example if the total number of rows
>   is 53 and the number of groups is five, the first three groups will
>   have 11 rows and the two remaining groups will have 10 rows each.

So with the NTILE method, you could get a few groups of 4, so the rest of them can be 3.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this...

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT *
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [period] ASC) rn 
FROM #test
 )
 SELECT [period]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (X.rn % 3) ORDER BY rn ASC) rn 
FROM X
ORDER BY [period]
```

Comment: Thanks.. I don't want to use `Row_Number`